# Encoding problems with SQL LOAD DATA INFILE? Or different

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encoding, mamp

I have a simple query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
INTO TABLE `test` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Province, Locality, Latitude, Longitude)
```

Problem is, I have two .txt files, each almost the same content, but different sources, so with file1 everything work perfect, but with file2 I have problems. First of all the output is like

> �K�a�m�p�o�t�

DB structure:

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Province varchar(255),
Locality varchar(255),
Latitude varchar(12),
Longitude varchar(12),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

my files:
[file1](http://xup.in/dl,77040935)
[file2](http://xup.in/dl,14963552)

Is it an encoding problem?

Comment: Which dbms, which platform?

Comment: Apache, MySQL 5.5.42 via MAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be `Kampot`??

Please provide the HEX for the source file.  It smells like you have UTF-16, not UTF-8.  Perhaps it came from some Microsoft product?

So, this may be the solution:

```
LOAD DATA ... CHARACTER SET ucs2 ...
```

Comment: It was UTF-16 LE and a binary file, I found out by opening the file via less. I will try your solution, thanks! :)